# How to parse text file with multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, parsing, delimiter

I have a text file I'm trying to parse. The data is a single string and uses four types of deliminators. There's also a record count at the end of the file that's not pertinent to the data that I can ignore.

Deliminators:

Beginning of data: ~
Field Seperator: |
End of record: #
End of data: ^

Sample text file:

```
~001|John|Smith|300#002|Abby|Williams|250#003|Tom|Jones|400#004|Claire|Benton|300^
Count:4
```

The parsed data should be stored in a list or collection of objects "Account"

```
public class Account
        {
            public string IdNum { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string AmtDue { get; set; }
        }
```

I'm still new to programming so please teach me what would be the best way to parse and store this data? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They should just put the source data into xml and call it good.  I know this is a school assignment, but I cringe at how many ways that could fail in anything real life.

Comment: Haha I _wish_ this was for a class assignment. I understand what you're saying and I totally agree with you. If I had a choice, I would change the format to XML in a heartbeat.  Unfortunately this is for a system of an older design that was dumped on me and I have no control over what it spits out. The data format is a restriction I have to work with. I just have to do the best I can with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know all delimiters, you can use something like this:

```
var s = "~001|John|Smith|300#002|Abby|Williams|250#003|Tom|Jones|400#004|Claire|Benton|300^Count: 4";

// select a line between "~" and "^".
var data = new string(s.SkipWhile(c => c == '~').TakeWhile(c => c != '^').ToArray());
var records = data.Split('#');
var accounts = records.Select(record => record.Split('|'))
  .Select(items => new Account
  {
    IdNum = items[0],
    FirstName = items[1],
    LastName = items[2],
    AmtDue = items[3]
  })
  .ToList();

foreach (var account in accounts)
{
  Console.WriteLine(account.IdNum);
  Console.WriteLine(account.FirstName);
  Console.WriteLine(account.LastName);
  Console.WriteLine(account.AmtDue);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Just first of all split by row delimiters, then split by field delimiter.

P.S. Don't forget check variables on `null` or array length like you need.

Comment: This is the first I've come across SkipWhile and TakeWhile. This is a much simpler, better solution than the regex rube goldberg that I was writing. Thanks for the help!